# Fix indentation with Terraform yamlencode

Tags: terraform, yaml, indentation, helm3

I'm deploying a helm chart with `Terraform v0.14.11`, using the `yamlencode` function to encode my values.

```
resource "helm_release" "foo" {
  name = local.chart_name

  chart     = "${path.module}/charts/${local.chart_name}"
  namespace = var.name-sp
  values    = [yamlencode(local.helm_values.foo)]
}
```

And this is what my `local_helm_values.foo` looks like

```
alertmanagerFiles = {
"alertmanager.yml" = var.slack_key != "" ? {
    global = {
    slack_api_url = var.alertmanager_slack_key

    receivers = [for k, v in var.receivers : {
      name = k
      slack_configs = [{
        send_resolved = true
        channel       = v.channel
        title         = ""
        text          = ""
    }]
    }]

    route = {
      group_wait = "10s"
      group_interval = "3m"
      receiver = "slack-notify"
      repeat_interval = "5m"
        }
    }
    } : {}
}
```

However, the chart deploys with errors and when I run the `helm get manifest` command, the indentation looks off.

```
  alertmanager.yml: |
    global:
      receivers:
      - name: slack_notify
        slack_configs:
        - channel: '#prometheus-alerts'

      route:
        routes:
          receiver: slack_notify
          repeat_interval: 5m
      slack_api_url: https://hooks.slackurl
```

Instead of

```
  alertmanager.yml: |
    global:
    receivers:
    - name: slack_notify
      slack_configs:
      - channel: '#prometheus-alerts'

    route:
      routes:
        receiver: slack_notify
        repeat_interval: 5m
      slack_api_url: https://hooks.slackurl
```

Is there a way to get the correct indentation levels?

Comment: The manifest YAML is a valid format, so something else is wrong here.

Comment: It seems `receivers` are indented more and `slack_api_url` less than inteded. Maybe the empty line between the two is causing it to indent it wrong.

Comment: I've taken out the empty line, but it's the same error. 

`line 2: field receivers not found in type config.plain\n  line 8: field route not found in type config.plain"`

Which is due to the fact that the indentation is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do.

If you look at the `values.yaml` file of the AlertManager helm chart, you'll see that `receivers` and `routes` stand alone and are not children of `global`

What you want is this.

```
alertmanagerFiles = {
"alertmanager.yml" = var.slack_key != "" ? {
    global = {
    slack_api_url = var.alertmanager_slack_key
    }

    receivers = [for k, v in var.receivers : {
      name = k
      slack_configs = [{
        send_resolved = true
        channel       = v.channel
        title         = ""
        text          = ""
    }]
    }]

    route = {
      group_wait = "10s"
      group_interval = "3m"
      receiver = "slack-notify"
      repeat_interval = "5m"
        }
    } : tostring()
}
```

I've added `tostring()` at the end to maintain consistent types on both sides of the True and False evaluation.